# What happens if you publish then immediately unpublish on Google Play?

Tags: android, google-play

So I accidentally published on Google Play (Oops, my bad, I thought I was submitting it for some sort of review), and 5 seconds later when I realized what I had done I immediately unpublished. I'm still waiting for the review for the iOS version and want to release both at the same time.

My developer console for the app has changed now, and it treats the app like an app that has been published (I can't replace the APK, can view stats, etc.)

So my question is this: Every day I wait am I losing precious visibility in the "New apps" feature page? Or when I republish in a few days will I appear at the top of the list as if I had just released that day?

Answer (score 0):

I believe re-publishing does not affect the initial publishing date, so yes, you do lose "precious visibility", but just because your app is new, does not automatically mean it will be on top of the New Releases category. There are probably several other factors that are weighed in such as ratings or downloads. Also, publishing your application does put it through review. It's just significantly faster than the Apple app store and assuming it passes the review, it will get published.